# Need to print mustache style literals to screen ("{{}}") inside angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, liquid, angular-template

Within my AngularJS application, I need to show my user that they can use [Liquid Markup](http://liquidmarkup.org/) inside of a text box.

Unfortunately, LiquidMarkup uses `{{ the_same_syntax_as_angular }}` and my explanation text is evaluated as Angular code.

- I do not wish to change liquid markups default delimiters.
- The escape char (`\`) does not stop angular from evaluating the expression.
- The sample text is within the `placeholder` attribute of an `<input>` tag. **It is not within a DOM node.**

How can I escape Angular's double mustache syntax to print an example?

Comment: How about using the html codes? `&#123;` for "{" and `&#125;` and "}"?

Comment: how are you injecting the text? `$scope.text ='{{some text}}';` won't get evaluated if set using expression `{{text}}` in view http://plnkr.co/edit/VvAjBIl9lfe1JBcahk1W?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<div ng-non-bindable>Ignored: {{ your Mustache example }}</div>`

**Working examples:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">
<div>Normal: {{1 + 2}}</div>
<div ng-non-bindable>Ignored: {{1 + 2}}</div>
<div>Ignored inside the placeholder: <input ng-non-bindable placeholder="{{1 + 2}}"/></div>
</body>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable

Comment: The text is in a `placeholder` attribute of an input box, so this is not quite what I was looking for, but looks useful for other use cases. I will update the question to mention that.